# MSYS2 OpenGL Setup

Tags: opengl, msys2

I am trying to wite OpenGL on MSYS2. I installed mingw-w64 packages like SDL2, glew, glm, mesa etc. But when I try to compile something like;

```
    gcc main.c -o main -lSDL2 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL
```

This is how I compiled things on Linux so i thought it would be similar. but -lGL is giving me problems. I can't find any OpenGL library for MSYS2. I installed mesa as i said but no luck. Should I use Windows version coming with driver and link to that? I don't know how can I do this though.

I copied OpenGL32.dll and lib files from my Windows to mingw64/lib folder and renamed them to libGL but of course this did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember correctly, on Windows these libraries are called differently.

Try `-lglew32 -lglu32 -lopengl32`.

Comment: Thanks, worked for this. Now linker says "C:/repo/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" Must be something about C runtime.

Comment: @meguli I think the problem is with your `main()`. When writing with SDL, you need to make sure that your `main` signature looks like `int main(int, char **)`. Is this how your main looks like?

Comment: @meguli the entry point for GUI application under Windows is actually `WinMain(HISTANCE *, HINSTANCE *, char *, int)` and not `main(int,char**)`. To wrap around that SDL usually ships with a `SDLmain` library that calls the regular main.

Comment: @meguli It means you need to add `-lSDL2main` before `-lSDL2`. I forgot about that flag. You *can* do manual SDL initialization from `WinMain(..)`, but this is not a portable solution.

Comment: In fact documentation says you need to link everything outputed by "sdl2-config --libs".

Comment: @meguli Then you should do that. But I think it should output `-SDL2main -lSDL2`, isn't it? This is how I dynamically link against SDL under Windows. If I use *statical* linking, *then* I need to link against another 10 or so additional libraries.